# Source of Quotation from Bhishma in Moksha Dharma Parva of Mahabharata "Kathamasmi Sahithyeva Sambhadhasyath"?

Tags: bhishma, madhvacharya, mahabharata

In [this](https://youtu.be/AIEqlw00Puw) discourse by Shri Bannanje Govindacharya @5:47 he mentions that Bhishma says  "Kathamasmi Sahithyeva Sambhadhasyath" in Moksha Dharma Parva of Mahabharata

What is the exact source of this quotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be talking of this shloka.

> yadA sa rUpatashchAnyo jAtitaH shrutito.arthataH |
> kathamasminsa ityeva sambandhaH syAdasaMhitaH || [12.211.34](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/txt/mbh12.itx) ||

here you can find it . It is in 44th section of moksha dharma parva. Moksha dharma parva starts from 168 chapter , and this shloka is in 211 chapter of shanti parva and this is 34th verse

Comment: But what is the meaning of it. https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b045.htm